# Command/option + tap a swift function to bring me to the swift source code from objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, hotkeys

In XCode 7.2.1, when working in swift code, I can command tap a function and it will bring me directly to the swift source code where that func is declared.

However, if I tap the same function from objective-c code, it brings you to the Swift.h Generated header file - not a very useful place.

Is there a way to go more directly to a function to the swift code using a key + tap combination?  Currently, I have to command + space and type in the class name/function and choose it from Open Quickly, which is not ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. The problem seems to be that Objective-C can't "see" Swift at all; all it sees is, as you rightly say, the generated `"...-Swift.h"` bridging header. This would make an excellent enhancement request at http://bugreport.apple.com (though whether anything can actually be done is anybody's guess).